# axis object error - The minimum value of the axis is greater than the largest data point value in MS line chart in c#

Tags: c#, charts

I am developing windows forms application with MS date time line chart using C#.net. (x-axis datetime, y1-axis double value, y2-axis double value) I need to add data points (live data) to chart for every 10 seconds. Initially chart show 10 minutes data. After that, I am removing first data point and adding one data point at last ( simply shifting). For this, I am changing axis min max values. My application run successfully for a week, after that getting below error.

> **Axis Object - The minimum value of the axis is greater than the largest data point value.**

Here is my code sample,

```
 if (datapointcount >= 600)    
 {           
    chart1.Series[0].Points.RemoveAt(0);                       
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = DateTime.FromOADate(chart1.Series[0].Points[0].XValue).ToOADate();
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = DateTime.FromOADate(chart1.Series[0].Points[chart1.Series[0].Points.Count - 1].XValue).AddSeconds(10).ToOADate();
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].RecalculateAxesScale();   
 }

this.chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(xval , value1); 
this.chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(xval, value2);                   

chart1.Invalidate();    
chart1.Update();
```

Comment: What is unclear about the error message?? We can't help any further since you don't show how you have filled `timestamp`. I suggest you pull out the values you use for  setting the Minimum and Maximum from the assignement so you can inspect them better..

Comment: Timestamp is double value calculated using ToOADate(), which will convert datetime value to double value.

Comment: Sure. But this is about the actual values! Look at them and you'll see,,

Answer (score 2):

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum += 1;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum += 1;
```

Works for my application. I also add value first THEN adjust scales.

The error is thrown because AxisX.Maximum is less than AxisX.Minimum

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was that I also have to convert my data to OADate()

this.chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(xval **.ToOADate()** , value1);

this.chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(xval **.ToOADate()**, value2);

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31424518)